# SQL pivot on multiple fields in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following code that returns results in the following format.

`Name|Col1|Col2`

**Code**

```
strSql = "TRANSFORM First([type.Value])) AS FirstOfValue" & _
" SELECT [Name] " & _
" FROM" & _
"(" & _
    " SELECT * " & _
    " FROM (table1 as o" & _
           " INNER JOIN table2 as type" & _
             " ON o.ID = type.ID)" & _
             " WHERE ObjectType = 'N'" & _
")" & _
" GROUP BY [Name]" & _
" PIVOT [type.Property] IN ('Col1','Col1')"
```

I need to however have it appear as follows

```
Name|PropertyID|Col1|PropertyID|Col2
```

The column PropertyID is stored in table2 in the format

```
ID|PropertyID|Col1|Col2
```

How can i have it appear in the format above?